# When fugacity and z-compressability equations instead of Gibbs free energy equations?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, pressure

In very high pressure environments such as mud circulating systems, conditions for polymers contain fugacity/z-compressability criteria instead of Gibbs free energy, more in the [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/41945/966). So

**When fugacity and z-compressability equations instead of Gibbs free energy equations?**

and helper questions to the latter

> 1. when are fugacity and z-compressability equations used?
> 2. When are Gibbs free energy equations used?
> 3. By which criteria can you justify your decision to choose between Gibbs free energy criterion and fugacity/compressability criterion?

Comment: Are you really referring to liquid systems (that are nearly incompressible), or are you referring more to gaseous systems beyond the ideal gas region?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic solids (like gelled drilling muds and elastomers) can not be treated in the same way as liquids and gases, using the z factor and fugacity (unless the loading on the solid is purely isotropic).  This is because, at equilibrium, a solid is capable of storing elastic energy (involving anisotropic loading and strains) after it is deformed.  As a result, the equilibrium state of an elastic solid cannot be described in terms of only two intensive variables (like it can for a liquid or gas).  In the case of an isotropic elastic solid, you need to specify either (a) temperature and three principal stresses or (b) temperature and 3 principal strains).  So, rather than 2 intensive variables, you need to specify 4 intensive variables.  All the thermodynamic functions, U, H, S, A, and G are functions of these 4 intensive variables.